# Automatically find files that start with similar strings (and find these strings) using Python

Tags: python, glob

I have a directory with a number of files in a format similar to this:

`"ABC_01.dat", "ABC_02.dat", "ABC_03-08.dat", "DEF_13.dat", "DEF_14.dat", "DEF_16.dat", "GHI_09.dat", "GHI_12-14.dat"`

etc., you get the idea. Essentially, what I want to do is merge all files whose names start with a similar string. At the moment, I do this by manually setting a variable `names = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]`, iterating over it (`for name in names`) and getting the respective filenames using glob `glob.glob(name + "*.dat")`. The merging step is later done using `pandas`. I don't just need the names/prefixes for finding the files; they are used later in my script to set the output files' names.

Is there a way I can automatically generate the variable `names` if I know that the files are all in the format `name_*.dat`?

Comment: why don't you just use  `glob.glob("path/*_*.dat")` to find all the files?

Comment: See my comment under your answer / my edit. I need the names/prefixes for the ouput files' names. Sorry for lack of clarity; I didn't want to add more (possibly unnecessary) detail than I already did to avoid confusion, but apparently that had the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this :

```
names = set([name.rpartition('_')[0] for name in glob('*_*.dat')])
```

This will get all unique prefixes before '_'. You will also want to set a correct path in glob() before matching.

Comment: why are you getting the names, why not just find the files in one step and why are you using a set?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham getting all unique prefixes in a separate variable is what author asked for. Maybe he has some other uses for it, I don't know.

Comment: no, they are using a list of prefix names to find the files `glob.glob(name + "*.dat")`, `glob("path/*_*.dat")` will find all the files directly, partitioning is just adding another step

Comment: @PadraicCunningham in that case user3's anwer might be a better solution than mine.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I asked to get the names/prefixes in the original question, because I want to use them later when i set the names for the (merged) output files. (You are right that I use them to find the files, but I also have other uses for them.) This is why I accepted Rusty's answer, although the one by user3 is also very helpful.

Comment: @FredS Thanks for clarification, also I didn't think about this when I wrote the answer, but you can actually replace the "set([])" part by set comprehension like so "{name.rpartition('_')[0] for name in glob('*_*.dat')}"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
result = [filter(lambda x:x.startswith(sn), fileNames) for sn in set([i.split('_')[0] for i in glob.glob("*.*")])]
print result
```

output:

```
[['ABC_01.dat', 'ABC_02.dat', 'ABC_03-08.dat'], ['GHI_09.dat', 'GHI_12-14.dat'], ['DEF_13.dat', 'DEF_14.dat', 'DEF_16.dat']]
```

Now, all files from result[0] are to be merged; similarly for result[1],...